# Why is my thread executing last even though I have put call to start first?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class test1 extends Thread  
{ 
   public void run() 
   { 
       System.out.println("Run method executed by child Thread"); 
   } 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
       test1 t = new test1(); 
       t.start();
       System.out.println(726*656); 
       System.out.println("Main method executed by main thread"); 
   } 
}
```

ouput is -

```
476256

Main method executed by main thread
Run method executed by child Thread
```

why thread statement is coming in last even when i called start method first

Comment: It does not generate the same output always because `Thread` does not gurantee it. Try running the program multiple times, output will change

Comment: If you want sequential output, there’s no point in using two threads. In this case just execute everything on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

When you call start, the new thread starts executing, but it does not affect the Main thread which is already executing. If you want the main thread to wait for new thread you can call a method like "join" on the new thread to wait for it to complete